# Change django createAt field

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have this model:

```
class Temp(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

sometimes I want to create an object of this class with a fixed time, but it ignores time and sets times with auto_now_add:

```
data = {'created_at': datetime.datetime.now()}
temp = TempSerializer(data=data)
```

what can I do?

Comment: An `auto_now_add` field ignores any value passed to it, it simply takes the timestamp when the object is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [**`auto_now_add=True`** field <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) ignores any value passed to it, it simply takes the timestamp when the object is created.

You can instead make it editable by setting the `default=timezone.now`:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils import timezone


class Temp(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: can I change this value in validate function in the serializer

Comment: @lornejad: yes but not with `auto_now_add`. As the documentation says "*Note that the current date is always used; it’s not just a default value that you can override. So even if you set a value for this field when creating the object, it will be ignored.*".